# embedding dll requirement in program

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, installation

I am writing a C# Windows application program and I'm using an add-on for creating chart in it,but when I run this program on another windows which has .net framework but not that package it does not work and give me exception.
I want to know how can I correct this problem even with setup file?
and if the answer is setup file then how should I do that?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you distribute your package (whether that's through a proper installer or just a zip file or whatever), you should be including the DLL as well.  Precisely *how* to include the DLL depends on what tool you're using to generate the installer.

If, for some reason, you are restricted to distributing a single .exe file, you can use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) to merge an arbitrary number of .NET DLLs into an executable.

Comment: @JGC: Then you might want to do a search for [`inno-setup`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inno-setup) or [`nsis`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsis) to get started.

Comment: Which setup builders have you tried, and what problems did you have? If none I suggest you look at Nullsoft NSIS (simply because I've used it before and know it's relatively easy). There should be plenty of documentation just a web serch away :)